# Image Link Rollover Effect

Tags: css, hover, rollover-effect

Does anybody know how to make an image link rollover effect similar to what is seen [here](http://demo.color-theme.com/?theme=Claystone)? Is there maybe a tutorial for this? Changing the opacity of the background and making the eye appear is easy enough but I have no idea how the developer got the cheese wheels to slide in like that.

Screenshots:

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of two things:

One is changing the position of the wedges on hover (in CSS).  I assume you know how to do that.

The other (the one that creates the animation), is specifying a transition time, so that it will move smoothly from one state to the other.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp for more details on how transitions work.

Unfortunately, cross-browser support is poor, and each browser uses it's own prefix.  The site you pointed to uses:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;`
```

Comment: That's wicked, I didn't think it was done with CSS alone I automatically assumed there was some JQuery behind the scenes but didn't think to check. Too bad about the lack of support, but it's certainly a nice effect to use for the people who can see it.